# Filter ldapsearch with awk/bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ldap, openldap

By writing an `ldapsearch` command such as:

```
ldapsearch -h ipaddress -p 389 -D "cn=func_01_acc,ou=admins,dc=akademia,dc=int" \
-w akademia.01 -b "ou=stud01,dc=akademia,dc=int" "(l=Torun)" sn cn telephonenumber -LLL |
grep sn: | awk '{print $2 "|" $1}' | sort | uniq -u
```

I got output:

```
 dn: uid=s21705,ou=stud01,dc=akademia,dc=int
 telephoneNumber: +78123793414
 cn: Benny Flowers

 dn: uid=s21711,ou=stud01,dc=akademia,dc=int
 telephoneNumber: +78123439058
 cn: Jacqueline Newton
```

The question is: how to format it to

```
Benny Flowers|+78123793414
JAcqueline Newton|+78123439058
```

The farest I went was:

```
ldapsearch -h ipaddress -p 389 -D "cn=func_01_acc,ou=admins,dc=akademia,dc=int" \
-w akademia.01 -b "ou=stud01,dc=akademia,dc=int" "(l=Torun)" sn cn telephonenumber -LLL |
grep sn: | grep  dn: | sed 's/telephoneNumber: //' | sed 's/cm: //'
```

And I have:

```
 +123123123
 Name Surname

 +123123123
 Name Surname
```

I tried to invert number and names with:

```
 for ((i=0;i<$elements;i++)); do
      echo ${array[${i}]}
 done
```

It printed output, but I cannot find out how to pass value to temporary array for names and for another array handling numbers.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Post the ldap output before you do the `grep sn: | awk '{print $2 "|" $1}' | sort | uniq -u` and we can help you. I don't understand how you can get the output you say you do though after a pipe that ends in `sort | uniq -u`.

Answer (score 2):

If you pipe your first output to:

```
sed -rn '/ telephoneNumber: /{N;s/[^:]*: (.*)\n[^:]*: (.*)/\2|\1/p;}'
```

You will get:

```
Benny Flowers|+78123793414
Jacqueline Newton|+78123439058
```

Use `-En` instead on OSX.

`sed` will search each `telephoneNumber` entries, `N` will place that and the following line together, `()` will match the name and the phone number and finally `\2|\1` formats the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

### awk

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '{split($0,a,": ")} /^telephoneNumber:/{tel=a[2]} /^cn/{cn=a[2]; print cn, tel}' ldapoutput.txt 
Benny Flowers|+78123793414
Jacqueline Newton|+78123439058
```

### shell

```
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=':' read -r key value; do
        case ${key} in
                cn|telephoneNumber)
                        read -r "${key}" <<<"${value## }" ;;
                *)
                        continue
                        ;;
        esac
        [ "${key}" = cn ] && printf "%s|%s\n" "${cn}" "${telephoneNumber}"
done
```

.

```
$ ./foo.sh < ldapoutput.txt
Benny Flowers|+78123793414
Jacqueline Newton|+78123439058
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^(telephoneNumber|cn):' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's#\s##' | sed -r '$!N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2|\1/'
```

Comment: Maybe a little comment as to how and why this works?