# LDAPSEARCH into table format

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

Is there any way to perform a LDAP search and save the results into a table format (e.g. csv)?

Cheers
Jorge

Comment: Perform a LDAP search from with what LDAP Client?

Comment: @jwilleke: openldap-2.3.43

Answer (score 10):

You can use the excellent miller tool ([`mlr`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

The last bit:

```
echo output | sed 's/://g'  | mlr --x2c cat then unsparsify
```

How it works:

- the sed converts the output to `XTAB` format
- `--x2c` converts `XTAB` to `CSV`
- `cat` then `unsparsify` makes sure the missing values are just filled instead of breaking to different csv output

Total command:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://<hostname>:389 -D "<bindDN>" -W -b "<base>" '<query>' -oldif-wrap=no -LLL cn mail telephoneNumber | sed 's/://g'  | mlr --x2c cat then unsparsify
```

Comment: This sort of works for me, but 1) don't need that `sed` and 2) `openldap` doesn't return fields in a consistent order. What works for me is run a query that would generate an expected list of a single attribute, then import and inspect that list, and run additional queries for alternate lists. Example: `ldapsearch -x '(&(uidNumber>=2000)(loginShell=/usr/sbin/nologin))' gecos | mlr --x2c cat # list disabled users by full name`

Answer (score 6):

**Just in case someone else has to do this:**

Based on the answer provided in 
[Filter ldapsearch with awk/bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529922/filter-ldapsearch-with-awk-bash)

this will output the LDAP info into a csv format:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D "cn=something" | awk -v OFS=',' '{split($0,a,": ")} /^mail:/{mail=a[2]} /^uidNumber:/{uidNumber=a[2]} /^uid:/{uid=a[2]} /^cn/{cn=a[2]; print uid, uidNumber,cn , mail}' > ldap_dump.csv
```

**NOTE**
You need to be careful about the order in which you parse the LDAP data with awk! It needs to be parsed in the same order as it appears on the LDAP data!

Comment: How would you deal with base64 encoded values in this pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answer of @rob-audenarde with the comments of @sebastian-stark and @dannyman, as well as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735968
I came up with this:

```
ldapsearch -o ldif_wrap=no -ZxLLL \
  | perl -MMIME::Base64 -pe 's/^((?:[^:]*)):: *(.*)/"$1: " . decode_base64($2)/e' \
  | mlr --x2c -N cut -f uid:,sn:,givenName: -o
```

This will always output the surname first and the givenName last, independent of the order in ldapsearch. The variant of @jorgehumberto won't work, since the order in the output of ldapsearch changes when an attribute is edited, the changed attribute will always appended to the list.

The Order of output (and indeed also the filter which attribute to show) is done in the tool [miller (mlr)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the subcommand `cut`:

- `--x2c`   ### convert tab to css
- `cut`  ### cut some pieces from the output
- - `-f field1,field2,...`   ### use only the specified fields
- - `-o` ### use the output order specified with -f above

The Perl one-liner modifies only lines with `::` and decodes the second part with perl-internal decode_base64. The `-o ldif_wrap=no` option to ldapsearch ensures that each attribute is indeed in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of the attributes you want in column you could do something like this

```
attributes=("$@") # e.g.("uid" "mail")
separator=','
quote='"'
ldapSearch <options> <filter> "${attributes[@]}" | \
  while read dn; do
    # read attributes below dn until an empty line is found
    while read attribute && [[ -n "$attribute" ]]; do
      # split name and value and assign the value to a variable named after the attribute name
      name="$(awk -F ': ' '{print $1}' <<< "$attribute")"
      value="$(awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' <<< "$attribute")"
      printf -v "$name" '%s' "$value"
    done
    # print quoted dn followed by ordered list of attribute values using indirect expansion
    echo -n "${quote}${dn#dn: }${quote}"
    for attribute in "${attributes[@]}"; do
      echo -n "${separator}${quote}${!attribute}${quote}"
    done
    echo
  done
```